# Frontend for spring kafka using angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, apache-kafka

I have a consumer which consume the data with spring from my kafka cluster. Now I want to create the UI using Angular. I've done writing it but I get this error in backend (java)

[image]

I know that kafka is NOT for multi threading and this error happens when I try to call the UI in the browser (frontend)

[image]

this is my **service.ts** code that connect itself with the spring

```
  private usersUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/receiptsData';
 }

  public findAll(): Observable<ReceiptData[]> {
  return this.http.get<ReceiptData[]>(this.usersUrl, { responseType: 'json' });
 }
```

and in my backend I also add this to my consumer to avoid the access block

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

if I can't have multithread access to my kafka from another source (angular, browser) what other possibilities are that I can access the data?

- sorry for my English, I tried my best to explain

**Edit:**

I use a Thread in my java because I don't want to use `while(true)`
this is my backend **Controller** Java Code:

```
public class ExampleKafkaConsumerController extends 
ShutdownableThread {

private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
private static final String RECEIVED_MESSAGE = "Received message: (";
private static final long DURATION = 5000;

public ExampleKafkaConsumerController() {

  super(DataUtils.GROUP_ID, false);
  ExampleKafkaConsumerConfig exKafkaConsumerConfig = new 
  ExampleKafkaConsumerConfig();
  consumer = exKafkaConsumerConfig.kafkaConfiguration();
}

@GetMapping("/receiptsData")
@Override
public void doWork() {
  
  consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(DataUtils.TOPIC_NAME));
    ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = 
      consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(DURATION));
    System.out.println(records.count());
    for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
      System.out.println(RECEIVED_MESSAGE + record.value());
      KafkaJsonConverter kafkaJsonConverter = new 
        KafkaJsonConverter(record.value());
      System.out.println(kafkaJsonConverter.
        convertStringToJsonObject().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my **Main** class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleConsumerRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(ExampleConsumerRunner.class, args);
 }

 @Autowired
 ExampleKafkaConsumerController exKafkaConsumerController;

 @Override
 public void run(String... args) {
   try {
     exKafkaConsumerController.start();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: The error comes from your server, has nothing to do with your UI or how you access it. Something in your Java code is using multiple threads, so you need to show that code

Comment: you are correct, I use Thread in my controller because I wanted to avoid 'While(true)', could you please see my java code

Comment: I suggest starting with this library if you really want to expose a consumer as an HTTP endpoint https://www.azkarrastreams.io/ Otherwise, the Kafka REST proxy already solves this for you and you don't need to write any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example, you're trying to receive latest entries from a Kafka topic via GET request. The error you displayed is because you're trying to use single consumer instance in the controller's doWork() method. To fix this particular problem you should have own consumer instance for every request (in the doWork()), but instead of doing it, I think you might want to revisit basic approach how you're solving the problem.

Reason is that it's not very typical to connect the endpoint directly into topic subscription - for the reason that you probably do not want to have each request connecting into Kafka separately (esp. with same groupId), this approach as number of downsides, and does not lead into performant or deterministic API.

I would recommend design where you have
a) server side data storage (singleton, in-memory database, or persistent database depending on your needs)
b) server side consumer subscribing to topic and writing records to the database. Spring @KafkaListener is easy way to do this.
c) REST controller reading the data storage done in step a)

With this design you can have one listener for the topic, decouple API from the listener, and it allows you to implement for example query filters to the API (latest, or entries since a date or a offset etc).

Comment: I moved the `subscribe to topic` and based on what @OneCricketeer said I deleted my `CommandLineRunner ` and this problem solved but it reads null data on Angular but it reads correctly in Java

Comment: @Space Angular isn't the problem. Test your API using cURL or Postman. Specifically, your GetMapping doesn't return a Response object. Printing only goes to the server console, not the HTTP server response... Also, Resource classes shouldn't be thread objects; that's automatically handled for you by Springboot

Comment: @Space Well, is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes my problem solved, it was because I was forgot the `GetMapping` to return Response object